# Get a Map<String, List<String>> from List<Pojo>

Tags: java, list, dictionary, collections, java-stream

I have a `Student` class with the following structure:

```
class Student {
    String name;
    int age;
    String grade;        
}
```

I have a `List` of `Student`s (let's call it `students`) like this:

`[{"Student1", 10, "A1"}, {"Student2", 12, "A2"}, {"Student1", 11, "A1"}, {"Student4", 11, "A1"}, {"Student5", 10, "A2"}, {"Student6", 10, "A1"}, {"Student2", 13, "A2"}, {"Student7", 11, "B1"}]`

Using the following code:

```
Map<String,List<Student>> groupedMap =
students.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Student::getGrade));
```

I am able to get a `Map<String, List<Student>>` like this:

```
{
"A1" : [{"Student1", 10, "A1"}, {"Student1", 11, "A1"}, {"Student4", 11, "A1"}, {"Student6", 10, "A1"}],
"A2" : [{"Student2", 12, "A2"}, {"Student5", 10, "A2"}, {"Student2", 13, "A2"}],
"B1" : [{"Student7", 11, "B1"}]
}
```

However, I want a `Map<String, List<String>>` instead of the above `Map<String, List<Student>>`.

The "key" of this `Map` would be the same, that is, the "grade" property of the `Student` class.

The "value" of this map should be the `List` of the names of all `Students` having that particular grade. Duplicates should also be removed from this "value" `List`, since there can be multiple students with the same name. Also, if possible, I need the insertion order preserved in this list.

For example, the output in this case would be:

```
{
"A1" : ["Student1", "Student4", "Student6"],
"A2" : ["Student2", "Student5"],
"B1" : ["Student7"]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following statement will give the result. Though duplicates would be removed and insertion order preserved in the "value" of the `Map`, it would however still be a `Set`.

```
Map<String, Set<String>> groupedMap =
students.stream()
  .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Student::getGrade,
        Collectors.mapping(Student::getName, Collectors.toCollection(LinkedHashSet::new))));
```

If, however, we need the "value" as a `List` only (of course with duplicates removed) instead of a `Set`, then we can use the following statement:

```
Map<String, List<String>> groupedMap =
students.stream()
  .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Student::getGrade,
        Collectors.mapping(Student::getName,
              Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                    Collectors.toCollection(
                          LinkedHashSet::new), ArrayList::new))));
```

Answer (score 1):

Whilst usage of this nested combination of collectors

```
Collectors.mapping(Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toCollection()))
```

as the downstream collector of `groupingBy()` seems to be a reasonable choice, I think it makes sense to make the logic of this nested collectors more transparent by replacing them with a single collector created with `Collector.of()`.

The overall approach remains the same. `LinkedHashSet` is used internally as a mutable container to ensure uniqueness and preserve the order. The result type of the reduction is `ArrayList`.

```
Map<String, List<String>> namesByGrade = students.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Student::getGrade,
         Collector.of(LinkedHashSet::new,
            (Set<String> set, Student next) -> set.add(next.getName()),
            (Set<String> left, Set<String> right) -> { left.addAll(right); return left; },
            ArrayList::new)));
```

Answer (score -1):

Use downstream collector to map the Student to name.

```
 students.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Student::getGrade, 
                         Collectors.mapping(Student::getName, Collectors.toList())));
```